# Is "more ... prices" an appositive phrase?

Tags: phrase-usage

> Profit margin decreased due to a change in product mix, **more products of higher cost of sales but with relatively lower selling prices**.

Is the above sentence grammatical? Is the phrase in bold ("more ... prices") an appositive phrase?

Comment: Sorry to have mislead you, Pupu, turns out it is indeed an appositive phrase, according to snailplane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's basically grammatical, although it's missing a word I would expect in standard English:

> <s>The</s> profit margin decreased due to a change in product mix, more products of higher cost of sales but with relatively lower selling prices.

There are times when you might leave a word like this out, and in the context I imagine (a formal report or presentation) it might be fine, but you didn't give us any context so I can't say for certain.

I do think it reads as an appositive.  First we have the noun phrase *"a change in product mix"*, and then next to it we have the larger noun phrase *"more products of higher cost of sales but with relatively lower selling prices"*.

Since the second noun phrase ① can be removed, ② is next to the first noun phrase, and ③ appears to describe the first noun phrase in more detail, I think it's fair to refer to it as "appositive".

The phrase "more products of higher cost of sales" sounds a little clunky or unnatural to me, although I understand it fine—the company had to spend more money selling the new mix of products.

Unfortunately, I'm not especially familiar with this sort of corporate report, so I'm not sure what to suggest in its place.  I assume "cost of sales" is a technical term and shouldn't be rephrased, but perhaps "more products **with** higher cost of sales" would work as an alternative.  (Should it be "more products with **a** higher cost of sales?")

You may want to wait for further answers or comments about the phrasing you've chosen.

Comment: +1 Undetermined *Profit margin* is conventional: you may think of it as a name, either of a category in a balance sheet or of a deity who must be served. It's the products, not the mix, which have the higher cost/lower price. You're right about the clunkiness. I would put a colon after *mix* and write *a higher proportion of products with a higher cost of sales but relatively lower selling prices.*